# Why is the CTRL + / not working?

Tags: functions

I've learned how to use this shortcut to [input fractions in the 2D form](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/Divide.html), it worked nice on my notebook but I can't make it on my desktop. Any tip on what could be happening?

Comment: Have you checked the default IME?

Comment: What does "can´t make it on my desktop" mean?

Comment: Please be more specific about both platforms (OS, language settings, keyboard, MMA version).

Comment: @YvesKlett In my keyboard, the  `/` is sometimes [behind a baguette](http://www.seriouseats.com/2008/08/baguette-bread-computer-keyboard-wrist-cushion-desk-accessory.html)

Comment: @YvesKlett It's a computer running Windows Seven 64Bits. My keyboard is brazilian portuguese. Any more details?

Comment: I am not really in the know there. Please add the relevant details (see @SjoerdC.deVries´ comment) of your desktop and laptop machines in the question and perhaps a link to your keyboard layout which might help others trying to help you.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You are not very specific in your details so I have to guess what may be wrong. I can come up with some possibilities:

**Keyboard shortcuts redefined**
Keyboard shortcuts are defined in the file KeyEventTranslations.tr. This is located in the directory specified by executing either

```
FileNameJoin[{$InstallationDirectory, "SystemFiles", "FrontEnd", "TextResources", 
              $OperatingSystem}]
```

or

```
FileNameJoin[{$UserBaseDirectory, "SystemFiles", "FrontEnd", "TextResources", $OperatingSystem}]
```

Shortcut definitions in file in the latter directory (if present) override definitions in in the former.

Search for a line that looks like

```
Item[KeyEvent["/", Modifiers -> {Control}], "Fraction"],
```

which defines the fraction shortcut. Check whether this contains the "/" character (default) or something different.

**Numeric keypad used**
Perhaps you normally use the "/" on the numeric keypad of your desktop. For this key to work the Numlock key needs to be set to the correct state.

**OS keyboard setting**
Perhaps the keyboard setting of your OS tells your programs that different keys are pressed than what's printed on the key. For instance, if I set the keyboard type of my (physical) US international keyboard to French, pressing the 'q' key gets me an 'a'. You probably have a Brazilian keyboard which [is rather unusual](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Keyboard_layout#Brazil). Some versions of Ubuntu [seem to have problems](https://www.virtualbox.org/ticket/7022) with that. My keyboard generates a ";" instead of a "/" when Windows is told it's Brazilian.

Comment: Oh, I've added some aditional details: It's a computer running Windows Seven 64Bits. My keyboard is brazilian portuguese.

Comment: It worked with the numpad's /. Thanks