# Some ctrl-dependent shortcuts not working as expected after update to Mathematica 13

Tags: keyboard

I recently updated to Mathematica 13 and now some of my ctrl-dependent shortcuts doesn't work. Ctrl+/ which is used for fraction and ctrl+= which is used for inline free-form cells doesn't work. In the math palette, I still see the fraction being mapped to ctrl+/, but under Insert→Typesetting, I see fraction mapped to ctrl+´ and the free-form cell to ctrl+` (and those shortcuts work). Some shortcuts, like ctrl+_ for subscript and ctrl+2 for square root still works. I got no clue as to why this happened, but I do know that it appeared directly after updating to Mathematica 13 (from 12, I think), and I haven't noticed it before updating. I use those shortcuts regularly so I think I would have noticed earlier if this problem was present on Mathematica 12.

I found this thread: [Why is the CTRL + / not working?](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/9369/why-is-the-ctrl-not-working) and found the keymaps in `/Applications/Mathematica.app/Contents/SystemFiles/FrontEnd/TextResources/Macintosh` (not in `/Applications/Mathematica.app/Contents/SystemFiles/FrontEnd/TextResources/MacOSX` that the code in the mentioned thread produced), and in the file I see `Item[KeyEvent["/", Modifiers -> {Control}], "Fraction"]`, so it seems like the problem isn't there...

Does anyone know a solution to this problem? I haven't changed keyboard layout or noticed anything wrong with any other program. Running macOS Monterey 12.3.1 and Mathematica 13.0.1.0 Student Edition on ARM, using Swedish keyboard layout